# Changing star colour onClick - why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple star rating system. The issue I am having is with an onclick event that is *supposed* to change the colour of the star when clicked.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn5ytthL/3/) for what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rating">
<span id="five-stars" onclick="vote(5); return false; 
document.getElementById('five-stars').style.color = '#ff6266'" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 5 stars out of 5">
&#9734;</span><span id="fout-stars" onclick="vote(4); return false; 
document.getElementById('four-stars').style.color = '#ff6266'" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 4 stars out of 5">
&#9734;</span><span id="three-stars" onclick="vote(3); return false; 
document.getElementById('three-stars').style.color = '#ff6266'" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 3 stars out of 5">
&#9734;</span><span id="two-stars" onclick="vote(2); return false; 
document.getElementById('two-stars').style.color = '#ff6266'" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 2 stars out of 5">
&#9734;</span><span id="one-star" onclick="vote(1); return false; 
document.getElementById('one-star').style.color = '#ff6266'" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 1 star out of 5">
&#9734;</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rating {
    color:#02dbdd;
    font: 700 26px/normal 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
```

Not sure why it won't change?

(The RTL thing is a whole other problem to tackle... lol)

Comment: JS stop execution when can't find ```vote(5)``` function. Add it and then it works.

Comment: I added it but that doesn't work, @Grievoushead

Comment: also you need to remove ```return statement``` from the ```onclick``` handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. vote function didn't exist.
2. You had return false so it didn't get to the changing of style.
3. You can also reference the element with this.
4. You were also missing the closing DIV tag even though this had nothing to do with your issue.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn5ytthL/5/

```
<div class="rating">
    <span id="five-stars" onclick="vote(5); this.style.color = '#ff6266'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 5 stars out of 5">&#9734;</span>
    <span id="fout-stars" onclick="vote(4); this.style.color = '#ff6266'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 4 stars out of 5">&#9734;</span>
    <span id="three-stars" onclick="vote(3); this.style.color = '#ff6266'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 3 stars out of 5">&#9734;</span>
    <span id="two-stars" onclick="vote(2); this.style.color = '#ff6266'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 2 stars out of 5">&#9734;</span>
    <span id="one-star" onclick="vote(1); this.style.color = '#ff6266'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Rate 1 star out of 5">&#9734;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have three different problems that directly impact your test:

1. You've configured JS Fiddle so that the code in the JS pane is wrapped in a function and executed on load. This means that your function isn't a global and is inaccessible to the intrinsic event attributes. Change the configuration of JS Fiddle or rewrite your code to bind event handlers with JS instead of HTML.
2. You've not configured JS Fiddle to load jQuery, so when you try to call `$.post` it errors because `$` is undeclared. Add jQuery.
3. You've put `return false` in the function before you try to set the colour. Naturally the function returns before it reaches that line. Remove the `return false`.

Comment: +1 for your number one point. I had to change that as well to get fiddle working in my answer but I did not mention it.

Answer (score 0):

JS stop execution when can't find vote(5) function. Add it and remove `return` from the middle of `onclick` handler then it works.

```
function vote(){}
```

Here updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn5ytthL/4/